# How to get data with axios from all api pages?

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, axios

What am I doing wrong? I want to get data from all pages in api. After adding the while it stopped working, but I don't know how to start the page loop differently!

```
    getCustomers: function() {
        let url = '/crm/customer/';
        return axios.get(url).then((response) => {
           this.customers = response.data.results;
           if (this.customers.length === 100) {
                let i = 2;
                axios.get('/crm/customer/?page=' + i).then((response) => {
                  this.c = response.data.results;
                  i += 1;
                  for (let item of this.c.values()) {
                      this.customers.push(item);
                  }
                  while (this.c.length === 100) {
                      axios.get('/crm/customer/?page=' + i).then((response) => {
                        this.c = response.data.results;
                        i += 1;
                        for (let item of this.c.values()) {
                          this.customers.push(item);
                        }
                      }).catch( error => {}).finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
                  }
                }).catch( error => {}).finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
           }
         }).catch( error => {}).finally(() => (global_waiting_stop()));
    },
```

Comment: the `while` is an infinite loop because you're confusing asynchronous code with synchronous code

Comment: @TKoL please tell me, what should I do better? I am a beginner

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is, first, use an async function called `getPageOfResults`:

```
async function getPageOfResults(page) {
    const response = await axios.get('/crm/customer/?page=' + page);
    return response.data.results; // .results.values()? I don't know
}
```

Then, inside another async function, you can have a loop that does what you want:

```
async function getAllResults() {
    const customers = [];
    let lastResultsLength = 100;
    let page = 1;
    while (lastResultsLength === 100) {
        const newResults = await getPageOfResults(page);
        page++;
        lastResultsLength = newResults.length;
        customers = customers.concat(newResults);
    }
    return customers;
}
```

So you've got a variable keeping track of what page your on, and you keep on getting new pages until you get a page with less than 100 results.

You're adding all the results together with the `concat` function, and returning the entire list at the end.

Comment: no problem. I use this pattern all the time in my own projects.